# Ktor, Netty and increasing the number of threads per endpoint

Tags: multithreading, kotlin, netty, ktor

Using Ktor and Kotlin 1.5 to implement a REST service backed by Netty. A couple of things about this service:

1. "Work" takes non-trivial amount of time to complete.
2. A unique client endpoint sends multiple requests in parallel to this service.
3. There are only a handful of unique client endpoints.

The service is not scaling as expected. We ran a load test with parallel requests coming from a single client and we noticed that we only have two threads on the server actually processing the requests. It's not a resource starvation problem - there is plenty of network, memory, CPU, etc. and it doesn't matter how many requests we fire up in parallel - it's always two threads keeping busy, while the others are sitting idle.

Is there a parameter we can configure to increase the number of threads available to process requests for specific endpoints?

Comment: Are you connecting to a database? If thats the case maybe you should create a connection pool.

Comment: No, it's CPU work.

Answer (score 2):

Netty use what is called Non-blocking IO model (http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/single-threaded-concurrency.html).

In this case you have only a single thread and it can handle a lot of sub-processes in parallel, as long as you follow best practices (not blocking the main thread event loop).

Comment: Here is what we are seeing - the system scales better when we have clients in different endpoints. For example, having two distinct endpoints sending requests from 10 threads scales better than having a single endpoint sending requests from 20 threads. And no, there are no resource constraints on the caller side. This leads me to think that the issue is related to requests coming from the same endpoint being allocated to a restricted number of threads, regardless of how many threads are idle.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to check the following configuration options for Netty https://ktor.io/docs/engines.html#configure-engine

```
connectionGroupSize = x
workerGroupSize = y
callGroupSize = z
```

Default values usually are set rather low and tweaking them could be useful for the time-consuming 'work'. The exact values might vary depending on the available resources.

Comment: We tried all of those, they don't seem to make a difference. We still see only two threads processing events, regardless of how many are idle.